# i am trying make an online music library, where admin will able to upload music files

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

i am storing the path of the .mp3 file in the database, but when uploading a file, the actual file is not uploading, just the name and the user info. here is the coding

```
<?php 
    if($_POST[ins])
        {

            @mkdir("songs");
            $spath="songs/".time()."-".$_FILES[sonsor][name];
            copy($_FILES[sonsor][tmp_name],$spath);
            $son="insert into `songs` values('','$_POST[sonam]','$_POST[soalmoi]','$spath')";
            //echo $s;
            mysql_query($son);
            header("location:songs.php?");//action=show&msg=va
            }

?>


<form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>Song Name</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="sonam"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Album/Movie</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="soalmoi"></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Song File</td>
        <td><input type="file" name="sonsor"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

        <td><input type="submit" name="ins"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

the file path is updating but the actual .mp3 file is not coping in the songs folder

Comment: Your code is **wide open** to SQL injection attacks.  Use parameterized queries with PDO or similar to fix this problem.  Also, you're allowing the client to specify file names on disk, which is not a good idea.  Someone could upload `somethingevil.php` and effectively do whatever they wanted with your server.  Never let the client control the file name.  Finally, your `Location:` header should be a full URL to be compliant with the specifications.  A relative URL is not sufficient, but will work with most browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you submit a file via POST to PHP, you must use **$_FILES** to get the file, instead of $_POST.

In your case, to access the file and its properties, you should use:

```
$fi = $_FILES["sonsor"]
```

Which is an associated array representing the file uploaded in the field with the name `sonsor`.

Now, to complete the upload, you most likely will want to move the temporary file to a particular directory and rename it according to what is in the database. PHP recommends `move_uploaded_file()`:

```
move_uploaded_file($fi["tmp_name"], $target_path)
```

The method returns true if it worked properly. It is recommended to put more safety checks into place; [check out W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) for an example.